# Copying the console messages in a text file using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to capture all the console messages in a text file using Selenium WebDriver. Can anyone please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Which programming language do you like to use? Java, C#? or what?

Answer (score 2):

I use [a simple Log4J appender to copy console output to a file](http://thegreenoak.blogspot.com/2013/04/a-simple-log4j-example-in-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in Java:

```
testResultFile="name_of_your_file.txt";
File file = new File(testResultFile);  
FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);  
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);  
System.setOut(out);
```

You can get pretty fancy with this (e.g. send to a specific directory, have the file automatically be named the test you are running, etc), but this basic version will do what you need.